# Sending Data over BLE from Central To Peripheral

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to use BLE to send data from smart device act as BLE central to BLE device act as BLE peripheral.
I know BLE is not designed for large data transfer, this is the requirement I have.

I have created [example applications both in iOS and Android](https://bitbucket.org/ranido/blespeedtest/overview). I manage to get about 333 bytes/second in iOS and half of than, 166 bytes/second on Android.

1. According to some sources iOS restrict the speed to 2KB/s to save battery life - I'm not close to that limit, can you say why?
2. In Android I think I have to wait for the `onCharacteristicWrite` before writing the next packet - it that right?
3. What can I do to improve the throughput from central to perpheral?

Thank you,
Ido.

Comment: Why BLE not classic Bluetooth? Where you should be able to get plenty of throughput no problem.

Comment: You are so right, but I have constraints I have to work with :\

Comment: Not familiar with the low level implementation, so I can only answer Q2 : Yes, thats the correct way.